# The java program always creates a new database

Tags: java, database, sqlite

My java project connects database with SQLite. (Sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2) No problem with connection. When program doesn't find database, immediately creates a new one. But I don't want it to, I want it to connect to an existing database, so it should not create new one. How can I do it?

My java code:

```
public class JdbcSQLiteConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:product.db";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
            if (conn != null)
            {
               System.out.println("Connected to the database");
               DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
               System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
               System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
               System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
               System.out.println("Product version: " +                                     dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
               conn.close();
             }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: get rid of `if (conn != null)`, it will never be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [SQLiteConfig source](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/src/cb3185b148726e00530779014e69d1475697084c/src/main/java/org/sqlite/SQLiteConfig.java?at=default), you can tweak [open_mode](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) to do what you want:

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:product.db";
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.resetOpenMode(SQLiteOpenMode.CREATE); // this disable creation
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, config.toProperties());
// ...
```

With this, if the DB exists, the code works, if the DB doesn't exist, you get an exception (with a rather strange message):

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CANTOPEN]  Unable to open the database file (out of memory)